# How to force VisualStudio not to create Win32 platform

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This is more question of curiosity, the behavior is annoying, but something I can live with.

I'm working on 64b only C++ application in Visual Studio. It consists of more projects, and I deleted the Win32 Configurations from all of them (and also Win32 Solution Configuration). But, when I add new project, it is Win32, and also creates Win32 + MixedPlatforms Solution Configurations, and I need to go to Configuration Manager and delete those.

Is there any configuration how to forbid this? I'm using VS2012.

Thanks

Comment: WIN32 is the name of the Windows platform API, it haven't changed with the introduction of 64-bit variants.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I'm not speaking about platform API, but about 'Platform' for VS project. You can select 'Win32' 'x64' 'ARM' there (on my installation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pre-baked in the project template that you selected to get your project started.  VS2012 makes it easy to customize that template.  Get started with your favored standard template.  Modify it, like using Build + Configuration Manager to first add the platform target you want, then deleting the Win32 configuration you don't want.  Etcetera.

Then use File + Export Template.  Keep the "Project template" selection, Next, fill out the dialog and save it.  Presto chango, pick that template for your future projects.